# Generate Java classes from Schema using JaxB with Inheritance

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I have this xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="figures" type="Figures" />

<xsd:complexType name="Figures">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="figure" type="Figure" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="Figure">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="argument" type="xsd:double" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="area" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

And this xjb:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="FiguresDefinition.xsd">
      <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Figure']">
        <inheritance:implements>figures.Figure</inheritance:implements> 
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

My idea is to create a Figure abstract class and use the attribute "argument" to create the objects.

But when I generate the classes I get:

[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?

I do not know if it is clear enough, but I would like to be able to instantiate Figure objects using the **name**, **type**, **area** and the **argument**'s given in the XML.